# https://localhost:5001/API/users/ can't be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

when I do `API> dotnet run` on console, it doesn't show the page of list of users. I'm using sql server express. Here is the github link: https://github.com/joshii22/DatingApp

Error I get.
[image]
These are the files I changed.

UserController.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersControllers : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    public UsersControllers(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppUser>> GetUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users.ToList();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<AppUser> GetUser(int id)
    {
        return _context.Users.Find(id);
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
       {
           options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
       });

        services.AddControllers();
      
    }
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{"ConnectionStrings" : {
"DefaultConnection" : "server = DESKTOP-QUO7HU2\\SQLEXPRESS; database = datingapp.db; Trusted_Connection = True;" }
```

DataContext.cs

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

When on run this must show.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In the code that we see, there is no endpoint that returns **all users**, only an endpoint that returns **1 user** (and it requires an **`id`** parameter). It is unclear why the "return list of users" comment is present because that is clearly not what the endpoint was built to do.

Comment: @PeterB I updated my question and it should show like in the bottom.

Comment: @AnjelloJoshua Please [edit] your question to include the result you get and/or the complete error message you get.

Comment: Please read your own code, there is no way in which `public ActionResult<AppUser> GetUser(int id) { return _context.Users.Find(id); }` can return a LIST of users, because it returns ONE USER (or null), and it requires an **`id`** to do so.

Comment: I honestly don't know how the code works. I'm still learning the new platform. I'm sorry.

Comment: I followed the steps of the video tutorial but I don't know exactly why it failed.

Comment: I see there is now also an endpoint with method GetUsers, which does return a list. But to make it work, you may need to change its HttpGet attribute to read `[HttpGet("")]`, so the system knows to use this endpoint if you make a request for `api/users`.

Comment: What's the output in the console? That should reveal enough information on what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better change the UsersController**s** to UsersController.

Or it will not be **detected as a controller**:

Or,you can change the Route to `[Route("api/users")]`, instead of [controller]

```
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    public UsersController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

The other code are the same as yours and I can get the result:

[image]

Comment: At first it doesn't run even I change the UsersControllers.cs to UsersController.cs but it run when I run first the weatherforecast and then api/users. Thank you and sorry because of my tiny mistake of adding extra s in controllers. Thank you so much.